# Regular expression to group prices and item name

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following examples:

`100k melon 8`

`200 knife 7k`

`1.2m maple logs 19`

I need to be able to take the first string as one group, the middle parts as another group, and the last part as the final group.

The current expression I have is this but regular expressions really throw me for a whirl:

`([\d+|k])`

Do any of you veterans have an idea of where I should go next or an explanation of how I can reach a solution to this?

Unfortunately, [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) doesn't really solve my problem since it's just a dump of all of the different tokens you can use. Where I'm having trouble is putting all of that together in a meaningful way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: @rsjaffe, as stated in the question, that does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
([0-9\.]+[a-z]?)\s([a-z\ ]+)\s([0-9\.]+[a-z]?)
```

[image]

and a quick overview of the groups:

```
([0-9\.]+[a-z]?)
```

matches any number or dot any number of times, plus an optional 1-character unit, like "k" or "m"

```
([a-z\ ]+)
```

matches letter and/or spaces. This may include a trailing or leading space, which is annoying, but I figured this was good enough.

```
([0-9\.]+[a-z]?)
```

same as the first group.

The three groups are separate by a space each.

Comment: why did you exclude the last [a-z]? from the group?

Comment: ah sorry that was a copy/paste error i updated the answer.

Comment: Spaces need not be escaped in character classes.

Answer (score 0):

***Solution***

This regex does the job

```
^(\S+)\s+(.*)\s+(\S+)$
```

See a demo [here (Regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/e0GaQd/2)

***Explanation***

- Explicitly match non-whitespace sequences at the start and the end of the string, resp.
- The remainder are the middle parts surrounded by ws sequences.

Comment: Recall that `[^\s]` is the same as `\S`. Also, this matches `melon 8 x` as the middle part of `100k melon 8 x 6` (because `.*` is greedy).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand your question correctly, you have the following String `'100k melon 8 200 knife 7k 1.2m maple logs 19'`. You should make a function that returns a `.match()`:

```js
function thrice(str){
  return str.match(/(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\w?\D+(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\w?/g);
}
console.log(thrice('100k melon 8 200 knife 7k 1.2m maple logs 19'));
```

Otherwise, if you just want to test each String separately, you may consider:

```js
function goodCat(str){
  let g = str.match(/^(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\w?\D+(\d+\.\d+|\d+)\w?$/) ? true : false;
  return g;
}
console.log(goodCat('100000k is 777 not enough 5'));
console.log(goodCat('100k melon 8'));
console.log(goodCat('200 knife 7k'));
console.log(goodCat('1.2m maple logs 19'));
```